# Cakephp, validate field if not required

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi i encounter strange problem, i have this `input` in my form

```
$this->Form->input('processing_data', array('label' => 'STH', 'required' => 'required'));
```

and this produces this html

```
<input id="UserProcessingData" type="checkbox" value="1" required="required" name="data[User][processing_data]">
```

my model validating this field is `User` model and code of it :

```
'processing_data' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Prosze zaznaczyć'
    ),
```

but let's say someone manually delete `required="required"` from input and then validation is not triggered i thought `'rule => 'notEmpty'` will do but nothing changed so next i added `'allowEmpty' => false,` but also it didn't help.
What can be done to validate this field even if required is not present

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
'processing_data' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Prosze zaznaczyć'
    ),
```

Comment: didn't help i use CakePHP 2.4

Comment: me to use CakePHP 2.4. Its the way to validate your form input. Look, I explain... The rule  notEmpty is determin your input is not empty or not null. Its not mean that one has to fill that input. But when we add required => true, then the user must have to fill that form. So, by any chance, if anyone manually delete required="required" from input, CakePHP will check that before its save on database.

Comment: hey Fazal I think notEmpty rule just check value of that field that is should not be empty or null, If user delete that field from the form using firebug than how can cake check so for that allowEmpty should be true its mean that field should be in form if user delete that field than cake throw an error.

Comment: Ok i debuged what was in POST and even if someone didn't check my checkbox in POST wwas 0 to it wasn't empty so i ended making regexp and now everthing is working good

Answer (score 0):

use required => true in model and you can true your allowEmpty validation if it is mandatory.

```
'processing_data' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'message' => 'Prosze zaznaczyć'
),
```

Comment: same as above didn't help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'processing_data' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'required' => true,
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'message' => 'Prosze zaznaczyć'
),
```